# Parsing string value to an Int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I have the following class with a int array.

```
public class UnitedNumbers {

public int[] num = {};

public UnitedNumbers(int[] _num){
    num = _num;
  }
}
```

In the following class, I am trying to parse the string value to int array, which I have trouble with.

```
public static WholeNumbers decode(String[] strNum){

    ArrayList<UnitedNumbers> _p_num = new ArrayList<UnitedNumbers>();
    int maxNum = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < maxNum; i++){

       _p_num.add(new UnitedNumbers(
               strNum[8 + i]
       ));
    };

    return new WholeNumbers(
            _p_num
    );
}
```

I have tried couple ways which i've uncommented. Nothing seems to do the trick.  What am I missing ? Can someone have a look? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried: Integer.valueOf ? Also, saying you are having trouble means nothing if you don't say what trouble you get. Maybe it's the input you provide that's not valid. BTW, a String is not "encoded" to an int, it's parsed.

Comment: Ive just reedited. I am trying to parse string to int array

Comment: ok, so, have you tried Integer.valueOf ? and what errors did you get?

Comment: Yes, i tried `Integer.valueOf(strNum[i])`. Since I have int[] in the constructor, its not applied

Comment: @Stultuske `error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to int[]` this is what I get when I try `Integer.valueOf()`

Comment: You need to parse element by element, not the array. Neither of the ways you tried was wrong, you used them the wrong way. iterate over the array, and fill the new array by the elements

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for comments. I will look for that :)

Comment: @Stultuske If you dont mind me asking, do you have any example related to this ? I can have look and proceed further

Comment: What are the contents of `String[] strNum`? What do you want to achieve with this line ` _p_num.add(new UnitedNumbers( strNum[8 + i]));` What is your general input and what is the expected output? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: @cantona_7 you mean to say you don't know how to iterate over the elements of an array? for ( String original : originalArray ) { int a = Integer.valueOf(original); print("a = " + a); } should do (of course with the complete print name)

Comment: yes, I am not familiar with this. Thanks for your input